# High precision frequency to voltage converter

Tags: voltage-reference, frequency-measurement

Lets say I have some 10MHz (+-0.001HZ) precision reference signal that I want to convert to quite a precise 10V Voltage reference. Unfortunately I don't have anything like a josephson junction available (or ten thousands...), and when I spend too much money my wife will kill me.

Looking around for semiconductor voltage references it seems that the highest precision is around 0.01% initial accuracy (the quantum volt doesn't seem to be ready yet), so to be much better than them, I would like to target, say, 0.0001% accuracy.

Looking into existing precision frequency to voltage converters, although having nice linearity components, even if they were sufficient, the devices would still require some reference calibration, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

So is there any technology that fits this gap? That is, intrinsic high precision frequency to voltage conversion without the need for calibration or laboratory grade equipment (and prices)?

Comment: If you need an accurate voltage source, why not get one, rather than trying to convert a frequency accurately?

Comment: @NickJohnson: Because they are terribly expensive, at least those I know.

Comment: I'm a bit confused right now, are you actually looking for a cheap high precision voltage reference, or a precision frequency to voltage converter which will also output 8V at 8MHz? And is there a limit to space - like it should be chip, board or bench scale (as in an additional instrument)?

Comment: @Arsenal: I am looking for a standard reference that does not need to be calibrated. It does not need to be really cheap, but not a many thousands dollar labroratory cryogenics device. About the complexity, size, and price range of an average rubidium frequency reference woule be preferred. Since precise frequency control is rather easy compared to precising things like embedded zeners or bandgaps I was thinking about there being maybe some conversion technology that is precise enough (but doesnt need to be as precise [and expensive] as a JJ.

Comment: An Rb frequency reference is fairly complex.. (just saying)  I guess I'd look at the various voltage reference IC's (Linear makes a spendy one.)  If you put N of the voltage references together and average the result your error should (in theory) decrease as 1/sqrt(N).. yeah I know you need 100 to get a factor of ten improvement.  Just measuring a voltage to 1 ppm is tricky.  Thermal emf and stuff.  What's the application?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: The application is mostly theoretical at the moment. But every once in a while I go and let someone calibrate all kinds of stuff I have for money. I would rather put the money into a device that gives me something that doesn't require it. A simple Rb reference is cheaper than calibrating all the frequency stuff once, and its nicer if you can calibrate more often and when you want. Same would be nice for all other kinds of measurements, voltage being the first that came into my mind.

Comment: Don't know if that's an option for you, but there are sometimes the [voltage reference boards](http://www.maxmcarter.com/vref/) of the Keysight 3458A multimeter around. But yeah those are also calibrated at some intervals - so probably not really an option, but they would at least fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

The Josephson junction is used as a voltage standard because it is based on fundamental physical constants and can convert a known frequency source into an accurate DC voltage.  Since frequency can be measured to a much higher accuracy than most other physical parameters, Josephson junction voltage sources can and are used as primary voltage standards. What you are asking is if there is any other technology that can compete with the Josephson junction.  As far as I know, the answer is no.

Comment: I found one but it isn't really what I would call available... http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.056802

Comment: @PlasmaHH Interesting but it appears very similar to the Josephson junction as the relationship between voltage and exitation frequeny is almost the same and depends on the same physical constants, e and h. It will probably be as expensive since it will require many devices to achieve a reasonably large voltage but time will tell,

Comment: indeed, but as a seemingly pure semiconductor device it will have the advantage of not needing cryogenics and who knows, maybe one day being in the same pricerange as a rubidium clock.